# Unselect DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".story-area > h1, .story-area > p, .story-area > div > p").text(function () {
        return convertString($(this).text());
    });
});
```

And a function:

```
function convertString(current_text) {
    var arr_text = current_text.split(' ');
    var new_text = '';
    for (i = 0; i < arr_text.length; i++) {
        if (arr_text[i].length > 4) {
            new_text += arr_text[i].replace(/[Hh][Ii]/g, 'HIV') + ' ';
        } else {
            new_text += arr_text[i] + ' ';
        }
    }
    return new_text;
}
```

My problem is that any tag under `.story-area > div > p` is being removed when text are replaced and I don't want that to happen. Any idea how can I do it? If i used the `:not()` selector, the convert string won't be triggered.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to preserve the tags and just replace text, you can filter to the [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) and use [jQuery's `replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to transform the contents of the node.

```js
function transform() {
  $('.story-area > div > p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('node', 'REPLACEMENT TEXT');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="story-area">
  <div>
    <p>
      Text node in .story-area > div > p
      <strong>Text in a strong tag that shouldn't be touched</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="transform()">Transform</button>
```

Comment: The thing about it is that not whole text are being replaced. Just a substring of the text.

Comment: Let's say for example, I will just replace text to tlouisext

Comment: @LouisMichael Sure, just put your `convertString` code inside the function passed to `replaceWith` and you can replace whatever you'd like.

Comment: Awesome dude!! You rock! Although I changed my code in a much simpler way :) @drew

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are re-setting the entire text that replaces everything including the elements within the selected object. Only change needed is to use *each* instead of text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".story-area > h1, .story-area > p, .story-area > div > p").each(function(index) {
$( this ).text(convertString($(this).text()));
});
```

});

The convertString() function remains unchanged.

Comment: Tried your code but still the DOM element was changed